# How to set model of a grid table to be a OData service

Tags: service, model, odata, sapui5

I have created an OData database from a CDS file. I have created a service in the `srv` module of my project which is accessible on http://thisisanexample.com/odata/v2/projectname. I would like to display this in a Grid table.

In the controller I want to have:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(serviceURL);
var oTable = this.getTable();
oTable.setModel(oModel);
```

(Where `this.getTable` is a function that returns the table I want to display the data in)

I currently have the `serviceURL` set to the absolute path but it doesn't return data.

Where do I get this `serviceURL` from (because I need a relative URL) and where do I set this service as a data source so that I can use the relative URL in the above code snippet?

I do not want to add a module that is created by a template, I want to do the binding manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set oData service in *manifest* file as a data source and you can get the model using `this.getModel()`in your controller. Then you can make a `GET` call for the `entitySet` using this model.

I hope you will get the data to bind to your table.

Comment: Would I need to add the service as a destination to do so? Because I’ve tried that and it doesn’t show up as a service.

Comment: You only need a destination if you're trying to make calls to an api deployed on another system. If you have your app deployed on the same system you need, as you say, the relative url that points to the entity where you want to do a "GET". Anyway, if you don't know wich url is that (kinda strange) you can use postman to try diferent calls on the oData service you created.

Comment: @GerardFandos where exactly do I do that? I have gone to the mainfest.json descriptor editor and gone to data source, I clicked add and clicked on service URL. It doesn't show my service as an option in the dropdown.

Comment: You can look at the sample worklist application to see how the model is defined in the manifest and then how the table is bound in the view:

https://github.com/SAP/openui5-worklist-app